# How to correctly use populate to link 2 collections in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using mongoose version 4.4.10 here are teh details of my schema.

```
var RespSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
  surveyResponseId  : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                   ref: 'SurveySResponsechema',
                   required: true,
                   index : true},
  customerSurveyId  : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                   ref: 'CustomerSurveySchema',
                   required: true,
                   index : true},
   version      : Number,
   question     : Number,
   responseType : String, // single or multiple-choice not implemented
   response     : [String],
   responseNum  : [Number],
  created_dt   : { type: Date, default: Date.now }

var SurveyResponseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
customerSurveyId  : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                   ref: 'CustomerSurveySchema',
                   required: true,
                   index : true},
deviceId    : String,  // whch Android Tableet is runing this
version     : Number,
taken       : Boolean,
created_dt  : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

mongoose.model('SurveyResponse', SurveyResponseSchema);
mongoose.model('Resp', RespSchema);


var Resp = mongoose.model('Resp');
var SurveyResponse = mongoose.model('SurveyResponse');

Resp.find({created_dt: {"$gt": new Date("2016-03-31T09:20:00Z")}})
    .sort('customerSurveyId' )
    .populate('SurveyResponse')
    .exec(function(err, results) {

    if (err) return err;
    console.log('results is:', JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

In the following find I am not able to acces the collection results of SurveyResponse as part of results
I only get the results of Resp collection.

Answer (score 1):

please try `.populate('surveyResponseId')` instead of `.populate('SurveyResponse')`

and, is `SurveySResponsechema` typo?
maybe it should be `SurveyResponse`.

Comment: Should populate have the name of the collection or the key that joins the collection's together? This did not work either.  I did not include the model is different from the schema.  mongoose.model('SurveyResponse', SurveyResponseSchema);